# Two notions of stability

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, quivers, stability, quiver-varieties

Let $Q$ be a finite quiver (i.e. an oriented graph). A representation of $Q$ is by definition a module over the path algebra of $Q$. More concretely, a representation associates to every vertex $v \in Q$ a vector space $M_v$, and to every arrow $\alpha: v \to w$ a map $M_v \to M_w$.

Given a “dimension vector”  $d: |Q| \to \mathbb{N}$, one can consider a “moduli space” of all quiver representations of dimension vector $d$ by taking $$
\bigoplus_{\alpha: v \to w} \operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{R}^{d(v)}, \mathbb{R}^{d(w)})$$ and quotienting by the natural action of $\bigoplus_{v \in |Q|} \operatorname{GL}_{d(v)}(k)$.

In general, the quotient is not a variety. However one can hope to get a variety after restricting to “stable objects”. There are two notions of stable objects which one might consider: (i) GIT stability, (ii) Bridgeland stability.

Question: are these stable loci the same (and if not, how are these related)?

Comment: A GIT stability condition is a numerical condition on the abelian category of quiver representations (in particular, there are many different choices you could make). Any choice of GIT stability will give you a space of stable objects for your given dimension vector.
On the other hand, a Bridgeland stability condition is given on the derived category of quiver representations. I'm not that familiar with the quiver case, but believe any GIT stability condition may induce one a Bridgeland stability condition.

Comment: Since no one has given an expert answer to this in a week, I guess I'll mention my old paper https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0702092. Warning that I was pretty naive about this stuff at the time, so no guarantees about the content.